# Scikit-learn out-of-core text classification memory consumption

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am trying to use scikit-learn to classify a large number of text documents, although I'm using the out-of-core functionality (with `SGDClassifier` and `HashingVectorizer`) the program seems to be consuming a lot of RAM (>10GB). I performed lemmatization and removed stopwords from the text data prior to this. I feel like I am missing out something important here. Can you spot a mistake in my code?

Thank you very much for any suggestion!

This is my python code:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import os
import re
import pyprind
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import HashingVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn import metrics

directory = "mydirectory"
batch_size = 1000
n_batches = 44
pbar = pyprind.ProgBar(n_batches)

class Doc_Iterable:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
    def __iter__(self):
        for line in self.file:
            line = re.sub('[^\w\s]|(.\d{1,4}[\./]\d{1,2}[\./]\d{1,4})|(\s\d{1,})', '', line)
            yield line


def stream_docs(path, texts_file, labels_file):
    with open(path + texts_file, 'r') as fX, open(path + labels_file, 'r') as fy:
        for text in fX:
            label = next(fy)
            text = re.sub('[^\w\s]|(.\d{1,4}[\./]\d{1,2}[\./]\d{1,4})|(\s\d{1,})', '', text)
            yield text, label

def get_minibatch(doc_stream, size):
    X, y = [], []
    for _ in range(size):
        text, label = next(doc_stream)
        X.append(text)
        y.append(label)
    return X, y


classes = set()
for label in open(directory + 'y_train', 'r'):
    classes.add(label)
for label in open(directory + 'y_test', 'r'):
    classes.add(label)
classes = list(classes)

validation_scores = []
training_set_size = []

h_vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1,1))
clf = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge', n_iter=5, alpha=1e-4, shuffle=True)

doc_stream = stream_docs(path=directory, texts_file='X_train', labels_file='y_train')
n_samples = 0
iteration = 0

for _ in range(n_batches):
    print("Training with batch nr.", iteration)
    iteration += 1

    X_train, y_train = get_minibatch(doc_stream, size=batch_size)

    n_samples += len(X_train)

    X_train = h_vectorizer.transform(X_train)

    clf.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes=classes)

    pbar.update()


del X_train
del y_train
print("Training complete. Classifier trained with " + str(n_samples) + " samples.")
print()
print("Testing...")
print()
X_test = h_vectorizer.transform(Doc_Iterable(open(directory + 'X_test')))
y_test = np.genfromtxt(directory + 'y_test', dtype=None, delimiter='|').astype(str)
prediction = clf.predict(X_test)
score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)
print("Accuracy: ", score)
print()
```

Comment: What's the total size of your dataset : 44000 documents? Have you tried applying a the HashingVectorizer to the full dataset? In my experience, extracting features from 700000 text emails without out-of-core approach takes less than 16GB of RAM, so your numbers are quite large. Unless the documents are very long. Reducing the number of features won't change it significantly anyway as it's sparse arrays with few hash collisions (I disagree with the response below).

Comment: Thanks. I have 3 million documents, I'll probably have to do more in terms of preprocessing to reduce the number of features / vocabulary size. Using Tf-idf seems to work quite well for a subset of up to 1GB of text files as input. I will also try to use the `HashingVectorizer` without out-of-core learning...

Comment: 3 million documents is fairly large. You should do a line by line profiling with `memory_profiler` to understand where memory is allocated (or not deallocated). If it's a script, running it with `python -m memory_profiler` should be enough...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adjusting `n_features` in the `HashingVectorizer`, for example:

```
h_vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(n_features=10000, lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1,1))
```

With the default parameters(`n_features=1048576`) you can expect your transformed matrix to have up to:

```
1048576(features) x 1000(mini batch size) x 8 bytes = 8.4 GB
```

It will be less than that because of sparsity but the coefficients of the classifier will add up:

```
1048576(features) x len(classes) * 8 bytes
```

so that might explain your current memory usage.

Comment: Thanks! I think the number of features is indeed my problem, I'll have to limit it by some kind of preprocessing.
How does the HashingVectorizer choose the features if the actual number exceeds n_features?

Comment: if there are more features than `n_features` then you will have collisions and two features might get binned into one. But that isn't that bad in practice because most words never get used (Zipf's law). You can make sure that's the case by measuring your CV score with different `n_features` and comparing to tf-idf. You can take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_hashing) at how the hashing trick works so that you get a better picture.

Comment: Yes, [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7513#issuecomment-252322348) are some more practical bechmarks on how decreasing the hashing table size decreases text categorization accuracy. I guess for 1e4-1e5 features, there should be almost not impact..

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer (sorry if I could not comment due to reputation issues) but I have worked on an image classification project.

Based on my experience, training using scikit-learn was very slow (in my case I used about 30 images, it took me almost 2-6 minutes to train a classifier). When I switched to OpenCV-python, it would only take me about a minute or less to train the same classifier while using the same number of training data.

Comment: Here the problem is quite different, because text documents are vectorized into sparse arrays unlike images represented by dense arrays (where OpenCV might indeed be more optimized).